# To convert calculation result from integer to duration in seconds

Tags: logstash, kibana

im doing some calculation for starttime and endtime in kibana using logstash. unfortunately i need the data to be resulted in seconds and not in integer number

below is my code used
code    => "event.set('duration', event.get('start_timestamp').to_i - event.get('end_timestamp').to_i);

Answer (score 0):

Anyway its resolved now ! by default the result would be in seconds